# Joomla 3 Media Queries being ignored

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, media-queries

I have been trying to write some media queries for a Joomla 3 Template that I am building (replicated from the Protostar Template) and unfortunately I am not having much success.

I have been trying to change the background colour that I have showing on a normal desktop and I then have the following media query:

```
#sidebar {
    background:#fabe04;
  }

// Landscape phones and down
  @media(max-width:480px) {
    #sidebar {
    background:#FFF;
  }    
}
```

but for some reason, this is being ignored as I refresh and nothing changes even though I have resized the browser window.

My current setup is that I have created another css file called custom.css and this shows the styles I have added for the normal size website but just doesnt seem to recognise the media queries.

If somebody could please advise would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Thanks makshh and nikesh. As I am using the protostar template as my base, the viewport tag is already showing up as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

and the stylesheet is linked as follows:

// Add Stylesheets
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/custom.css');

The custom stylesheet is showing all the stylesheets for my template but just doesnt recognise the media queries.

I also tried to add the !important to the style within my media query but nothing changes.

Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: Did you try add !important rules to your styles? It can be specificity issue.

Answer (score 0):

First check your view port meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then check your media query's, make them similar in syntax !!

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px){

}// or else

@media (max-width:400px){

}
```

After you check these, Always add the media query at the end of your css. or if you use external css for media query link them as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media.css" />
```

last option is to use !important

```
@media(max-width:480px) {
    #sidebar {
      background:#FFF !important;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks makshh and nikesh. I have checked and I still dont get the see the changes when i resize the browser to below 480px.

Comment: As i am using the protostar template as my base the viewport tag is already showing

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: and the link to the stylesheet is as follows

Comment: Are you sure you have your custom css below your protostar template css.
Check it from your browser by viewing source code.

Comment: if you change the `background-color` of `<body>` in the media query does it trigger now?

Comment: Just checked the source and the custom.css definitely appears after the template.css. I even tried changing the body background and container within the media query and still doesnt work.. Might have try on another test site...

Comment: change your media query to 500px Or  zoom out by clicking (ctrl-) and resize your browser